# Tire direction on Miami Sun tricycle

Tags: tire

The tires on my Miami Sun tricycle have chevrons that point in the opposite direction and the label on the side wall which reads drive direction.
Do I align the tires using the chevron or the arrow stamped on the side wall ?

Answer (score 4):

I would generally default to the drive direction indicated on the side wall of the tire.

I know folks that run tires opposite of that recommendation for specific reasons (traction gains at the cost of rolling resistance), but generally, the manufacturer knows what they are doing when they put that arrow on the sidewall.

Comment: In all likelihood, its going to make a negligible difference on a tricycle.

Comment: True, but if we are asking the correct way to do it, there it is.  Additionally, the tire labeling on the drive side (or outside in the case of a trike) should be centered over the valve hole.